# Cannot cast double values as String to textview

Tags: java, android

I got a null pointer exeption error on Attempt to invoke virtual method `void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'` on a null object reference.

```
public class MainActivity {
    TextView servingqueue;
}
```

This is onCreate

```
    DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mServingQueue = mRootRef.child("ServingQueue");

servingqueue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.queueServing);

mServingQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Double number = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
        servingqueue.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
```

The error appeared right on

```
servingqueue.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```

It just does not want to pass the value from Firebase to my textview. I get force close from my app upon loading the activity.

Comment: is it `servingqueue` or `mServingQueue`?

Comment: `mServinQueue` is referencing my earlier code which is
`DatabaseReference mServingQueue = mRootRef.child("ServingQueue");`

Comment: exception stack trace?

Comment: `servingqueue` is null.

Comment: `findViewById()` may be returning null

Answer (score 0):

First Cast Double to double(primitive) then Cast it to String

```
Double number = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
 double d=number.doubleValue();
        servingqueue.setText(String.valueOf(d));
```

Comment: How would this help?

Comment: I still get the same error after casting that.

Comment: then check whether number(Double) is null or not?